# Tkinter mainloop exits unexpectedly after speaking text with pyttsx

Tags: python, tkinter, text-to-speech

I am creating a small program that uses tkinter and pyttsx for interaction with the user. For some reason the script exits after having said 'button clicked', while it should stay in the mainloop. Even stranger, it does not even pass the 'checkpoint' I added below the mainloop.

Here's a simplified version of the code that produces the error:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pyttsx

def button_click():
    engine.say('button clicked')
    engine.runAndWait()

engine = pyttsx.init()

root = tk.Tk()
gameframe = tk.Frame(root)
gameframe.pack()
readybutton = tk.Button(gameframe, text = 'click', command = button_click)
readybutton.pack()

root.mainloop()

print('checkpoint')
```

How to solve this problem?

Update:
via Google I found some indications this issue may have something to do with both tkinter and pyttsx using event loops, and with how Apple's Foundation and/or ObjC modules handle events. Since I'm a newbie to Python, I don't understand it well but some of you might, see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyobjc.devel/5965.

I also found an almost-too-simple, mac-specific workaround that avoids using pyttsx completely:

```
import os

phrase = 'button clicked'
os.system("/usr/bin/say " + phrase)
```

This works well, also in combination with tkinter :-)

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it is exiting the main loop? If it's not getting to that final print statement, the main loop isn't "exiting", your program is crashing. Based on the evidence you're giving, the crash is happening in the method `engine.runAndWait()`.

If your program is not crashing, and what you really mean is that the program is no longer responding to events, then the only explanation is that `engine.runAndWait()` is blocking. Why that's happening I don't know because I've never used pyttsx, though the documentation for `runAndWait` says it will block until all queued events have been process Perhaps it thinks there is still something in the queue.

Comment: You're right, I can't tell if it actually exits the main loop. You may well be right it crashes in the method runAndWait(). Here's what I see: after the program said 'button clicked', it just terminates like it reached the end of the code. The Tkinter GUI that was created (the button) disappears and my Terminal (mac) returns to command line input mode. Also I don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

pyttsx falls apart when you call its Engine methods from different threads, even when they never overlap in time. (Not just *runAndWait* but things like *say*, too.) *startLoop* and *runAndWait* block.

I had to write a thread-safe wrapper around pyttsx. All functions from pyttsx need to go in the same thread.

If you're using *startLoop*, be careful not to let the 'finished-utterance' callback return when the command queue is empty, or you won't be able to access the loop again, but *startLoop* won't return either. I think I had problems with *runAndWait*.

Also, calling *Engine.stop* from a callback seems to make things stop working properly. (But you can't call it from anywhere else, either.) Never feed *say* an empty string or a non-ascii character. (Possibly platform-dependent).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you use pyttsx3. Its much more recent, faster, and overall easier to program with. The voice it uses is entirely based on your system's text to speech api like sapi 5 for Windows.